# How to add effect around the checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating a checkbox style where I use vector image.

I'm using material design, how can I put this effect around the checkboxes

My StyleCode:

```
<Style x:Key="styleCustomCheckBox" 
       TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="imageCheckBox" 
                           Source="{StaticResource CheckBoxCheckImage}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" 
                                Property="Source" 
                                Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxSquareImage}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

How can I apply the same effect of Material Design in my style?

Example of the effect around the checkbox in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks very similar to the material design in xaml template.

You could consider just using the nuget package.

If that doesn't suit then use or  base your own template on the one from there:

https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.CheckBox.xaml

Tyere are a couple of variations and although there's the ellipse in there, i'm not sure it's an exact match for your requirement. Looks very close though.

Comment: I use Material Design but I want to create my own style for the checkbox, I just want to implement this effect around my checkbox